# Refresh cache for specific image (avatar upload)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My site has an avatar upload feature that lets users upload an avatar. The problem is, if the user tries to upload another avatar, their browsers cache keeps showing their previous avatar until they do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) or clear their browser's cache.

Currently, this is what I do to display an avatar:

```
<img src="{{ secure_asset('storage/avatars/' . $user_id . '/avatar.png') }}" />
```

How can I refresh the cache for the avatar after the user uploads a new one so that it shows their latest avatar instead of their old one?

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage "cache-busting". When you save the image, you can save a version number to the users table. So the first time a user saves an avatar, set a `avatar_version` column to `1`. Increment the version number when uploading a new avatar. So when you grab it you can call

```
<img src="{{ secure_asset('storage/avatars/' . $user_id . '/avatar.png')."?version=".$user->avatar_version }}" />
```

If the GET parameter changes, it wont affect the file but the browser will recognize it as a different image and grab this new one.

Answer (score -1):

caching is done by the browser and from the server side you don't have any control over browser caching functionality so you can not update users browser cache from the backend.

you can explicitly tell browser not to cache that specific web page by passing appropriate http headers. so that that particular page will always be loaded from the server rather than the cache.

for php you can use below headers

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

you can also do this with HTML as well

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 14 Aug 2017 12:12:12 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: How then do sites like Twitter and Facebook refresh the cache for just profile pictures?